# React enzyme + jest how to test onSubmit

Tags: jestjs, axios, enzyme, react-functional-component

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
 .preventDefault();
 if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(value)) {
  setError(true);
  return;
 }
if (loading) return;
  setError(false);
  setLoading(true);
  return Axios.post("/send-email", { value, messageHtml }).then(() => {
   clearTimeout(timerId);
   setSuccess(true);
   setLoading(false);
   setValue("");
   timerId = setTimeout(() => {
    setSuccess(false);
   }, 5000);
    }).catch(() => setLoading(false));
  };

render(
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} id="get-list-form" autoComplete="off">
 <input
   value={value}
   required
   onChange={handleChange}
   className="input 
   placeholder="Enter your email "
   type="text"
  />  
<button type="submit" className={`button ${btnClass}`}>{btnMessage}</button>
 </form>
);
```

> **i have this code. this is a functional component.**
>       and how can i test handleSubmit  function?? or intercept axios call?
>       its called on onSubmit event.
>       its called on onSubmit event.

```
wrapper.find('form') .simulate('submit', { preventDefault () {} });

**this code successfuly called onSubmit on form,
but i dont understand how to test axios call inside her.**
```

Comment: create a mock function for Axios.post and get it return a resolved promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mock `axios.post()` function In your test file so that `axios.post()` returns a resolved promise.

```
import * as axios from 'axios';
import MyComponent from '../MyComponent';

jest.mock('axios');// this should come immediately after imports

test('MyComponent handle submit', ()=>{
   axios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve());

   // rest of your test
});
```

For more info, you can have a look at [Jest mock functions doc](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html)

Reason for mocking axios immediately after imports is discussed [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5993#issuecomment-381410033).

Comment: hi tnh for help but, i write this code,
return axios.post("/send-email").then(() => {
      expect(wrapper.find(Spinner)).toHaveLength(0);
      expect(wrapper.contains(
        <p className="input-message">
          Success! Check your email for access to 1000 investment bankers in NYC.
        </p>
      )).toBe(true);
    });
and get error (Cannot read property 'then' of undefined)

Comment: it("show success message if success fetch", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<GetListForm btnClass="blue" />);
    axios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve());
    wrapper.find("input").simulate("change", { target: { value: "email@email.com" } });
    expect(wrapper.find("input").prop("value")).toBe("email@email.com");
    wrapper.find("button").simulate("submit", { preventDefault() { } });
    expect(wrapper.find(Spinner)).toHaveLength(1);
    return axios.post("/send-email").then(() => {
      expect(wrapper.find(Spinner)).toHaveLength(0);
    });
  });